# Power BI: Enterprise Gateway can't connect: "NULL SID" in Eventlog

Tags: powerbi

I want to connect multidimensional cubes within Power BI. It's working in Power BI Desktop within our local domain.
After publishing the report to Power BI I set up the Power BI Enterprise Gateway on our development Server (see Details below). The Power BI Services can connect to my Gateway, the Database Server and the Analysis Server. But it can't load the cubes when I click into "dataset" or "reports".
I guess it's the same problem as this post ("NULL SID"):
http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Enterprise-Gateway-with-trial-account/td-p/15400

Thats the Eventlog:
Fehler beim Anmelden eines Kontos.
Antragsteller:
Sicherheits-ID: myDomain\Administrator
Kontoname: Administrator
Kontodomäne: myDomain
Anmelde-ID: 0x20A3A
Anmeldetyp: 3
Konto, für das die Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen ist:
Sicherheits-ID: NULL SID
Kontoname:
Kontodomäne:
Fehlerinformationen:
Fehlerursache: Unbekannter Benutzername oder ungültiges Kennwort.
Status: 0xC000006D
Unterstatus:: 0xC0000064
Prozessinformationen:
Aufrufprozess-ID: 0x664
Aufrufprozessname: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSAS12.SQL2014\OLAP\bin\msmdsrv.exe
Netzwerkinformationen:
Arbeitsstationsname: DEVSRV
Quellnetzwerkadresse: -
Quellport: -
Detaillierte Authentifizierungsinformationen:
Anmeldeprozess: OLAPSvc
Authentifizierungspaket: Kerberos
Übertragene Dienste: -
Paketname (nur NTLM): -
Schlüssellänge: 0
Dieses Ereignis wird beim Erstellen einer Anmeldesitzung generiert. Es wird auf dem Computer generiert, auf den zugegriffen wurde.
Die Antragstellerfelder geben das Konto auf dem lokalen System an, von dem die Anmeldung angefordert wurde. Dies ist meistens ein Dienst wie der Serverdienst oder ein lokaler Prozess wie "Winlogon.exe" oder "Services.exe".
Das Anmeldetypfeld gibt den jeweiligen Anmeldetyp an. Die häufigsten Typen sind 2 (interaktiv) und 3 (Netzwerk).
Die Felder für die Prozessinformationen geben den Prozess und das Konto an, für die die Anmeldung angefordert wurde.
Die Netzwerkfelder geben die Quelle einer Remoteanmeldeanforderung an. Der Arbeitsstationsname ist nicht immer verfügbar und kann in manchen Fällen leer bleiben.
Die Felder für die Authentifizierungsinformationen enthalten detaillierte Informationen zu dieser speziellen Anmeldeanforderung.
- Die übertragenen Dienste geben an, welche Zwischendienste an der Anmeldeanforderung beteiligt waren.
- Der Paketname gibt das in den NTLM-Protokollen verwendete Unterprotokoll an.
- Die Schlüssellänge gibt die Länge des generierten Sitzungsschlüssels an. Wenn kein Sitzungsschlüssel angefordert wurde, ist dieser Wert 0.

Windows Server: Windows Server 2012 R2
Database: SQL Server 2016 (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (CTP3.2) - 13.0.900.73 (X64))
Analysis Server: SQL 2014 (Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU4) (KB3106660) - 12.0.4436.0 (X64))
Power BI Enterprise Gateway: Fileversion from EnterpriseGatewayConfigurator.exe: 11.0.9169.180

Crossport from: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Enterprise-Gatway-can-t-connect-quot-NULL-SID-quot-in/m-p/15659#M5066

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The powerbi.com email was not the same configured in the UPN!

I had to configure the UPN in our local network. (COMPANY.local and company.onmicrosoft.com)

Thansk to this reply: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Enterprise-Gateway-with-trial-account/td-p/15400